# what are the contents of System.out.println of Database object

Tags: java, jdbc

On 
`System.out.println(databaseConnection);`

I got

```
jdbcconnection.DatabaseConnection@43bf3d77
```

Can anyone explain this text in details more importantly "43bf3d77"?

Comment: This is the default String returned by calling `toString()` on any reference variable that does not override this method. But more importantly, it makes no sense trying to print out the `toString()` of a database connection. What do you expect it should print? "null"? I have a strong suspicion that you should be checking something else.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels maybe the OP is expecting the contents of the database...

Comment: @BoristheSpider: I agree, hence my "strong suspicion that you should be checking something else".

Answer (score 4):

Because `DatabaseConnection` class doesn't override, Object class `toString()` method will be used :

```
  public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }
```

It is Hex String of hashcode.

As Paul commented, it is useless for programmer.

Comment: Are you talking about @Hovercraft Full of Eels when mentioning "Paul"? I am really curious if that is the case.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei: No, it seems Paul removed his/her comment.

Comment: It does have marginal use. If two references have different hash codes, they point to different objects.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: Correct, but I think through program you can't perform anything using this value.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Not necessarily, if `hashCode()` was overridden, it is entirely possible that two different objects have the same hashcode.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Look again at what I wrote. I did not say that having the same hash code implies being the same object, only that having different hash codes implies being different objects.

Answer (score 2):

As the class `DatabaseConnection` doesn't override the default implementation of `toString()` (by [`Object class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)), you see the class name with its hashcode.

Answer (score 1):

jdbcconnection.DatabaseConnection means that databaseConnection is a Database Connection, a subset of Java Database Connectivity Connection. @43bf3d77 shows "@", followed by the hashcode of databaseConnection written in hexadecimal.

Comment: If you want a more detailed answer, read Nambari's one. I just gave a basic answer on what I know now, while he/she inserted the toString method as confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

The string *`43bf3d77`* is returning from the method `hashCode` of the `databaseConnection` object (see the answer of Nambari). The default implementation is converting the *internal address* of the object into an integer (but this depends on the implementation of the virtual machine, may be a truncated version or a codified version of the address of the object in memory. e.g. [JRockit](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13188_01/jrockit/docs81/portblty/codeprac.html#999418))